# How do you get the value of a key in a big map using tezos-client?

Tags: tezos-client

How do you get the value of a key in a big map using tezos-client? I don’t get the parameter « identifier of big_map » of « get element  of big map , or how to find this identifier. The « get big map value for» is simpler to understand but deprecated.

And how do you discover the indexes of the big maps of a contract? It seems you would have to inspect the storage, and correlate with the type of the storage, and pick out the numbers that correspond to big_maps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the old route is that it used POST to simplify the fact it was sending a JSON body, but semantically POST was incorrect because it was not changing anything.
The current version requires the key to be in script_expr form. The big map id is an integer. When you originate a contract it will give you the ids of its big maps. When you query the store of a contract, instead of returning []  for the big map like it did before, now it returns the big map id.
You can also view this thread: [How to get big map value on Babylon](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/how-to-get-big-map-value-on-babylon)

regarding the second question: 
If you don't mind using an API other then the node RPC you can find this in the new version of the tzstats indexer (GET /explorer/contract/{hash} returns an object with a key bigmap_ids which is an array) see https://api.babylonnet.tzstats.com/explorer/contract/KT1E5toJrALhVPuKpHWTbRVjgEvWWR98sVKj for an example, the id is also part of the decoded/unboxed storage endpoint at https://api.babylonnet.tzstats.com/explorer/contract/KT1E5toJrALhVPuKpHWTbRVjgEvWWR98sVKj/storage