# Are bigmaps stored on-chain or off-chain?

Tags: storage, bigmap, ipfs

I can't find details on this, but from my experiments it seems like bigmaps rely on ipfs while maps are on-chain.

Is this understanding correct?

If not, where are bigmaps stored, and is it possible to use information from inside a bigmap inside a synchronous on-chain view call from another contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

big_maps are stored lazily onchain. Regarding using information from inside a big_map inside an onchain view, you can do that, but you can't have the view return the whole big_map, only specific values.

Comment: thank you for the additional information, can you return all available types, or is there a subset of variable types that can be returned?

Comment: You can see information about views here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/active/michelson.html#operations-on-views 
Basically, return type of a view can be anything accept `ticket`, `operation`, `big_map` and `sapling_state`. The same goes for their input type.

Answer (score 1):

BigMaps are indeed stored on-chain. There is no IPFS integration in Tezos.

See this [previously answered question](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/how-to-get-big-map-value-on-babylon) about fetching bigmap data from the chain.

Comment: ah fantastic, thank you for clarifying. regarding ipfs though, isn't that how off-chain views are stored?

Comment: @0x10 There is absolutely, 100%, no IPFS integration with anything Tezos. Not sure where you keep seeing this, but there is NO IPFS in Tezos at all. Nothing. None. 0. Zilch.

Comment: it's pretty easy to arrive at that conclusion if your tezos journey begins through chrome inspector and nfts, where most storage of tzip-16 and tzip-21 metadata is on ipfs, and the documentation doesn't say that it isn't integrated, so it's initially unclear because using taquito leads to dozens of ipfs connections :)

Comment: NTFs are just an application which is implemented on the Tezos platform. There's no requirement for NFTs to use IPFS either, it's just a choice for the dapp developer. The integration you see is between IPFS and the application, not IPFS and Tezos.

Comment: thank you for clarifying